# Fog Changing by position transform.position.y

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

I need the fog to change two times once on the level of y150 and second time on the level y90. I wanted to set the 
`gameObject.transform.position.y`
to function only from y150 to y80 but I cant figure out how its done.

thank you very much here is my code so far

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {


}

bool IsUnderwater(){

    return gameObject.transform.position.y < 150;
    RenderSettings.fog = true;
    RenderSettings.fogColor = new Color (0.15f, 0.35f, 0.40f, 0.5f);
    RenderSettings.fogDensity = 0.03f;

}
bool IsNotUnderwater(){

    return gameObject.transform.position.y < 90;
    RenderSettings.fog = true;
    RenderSettings.fogColor = new Color (0.8f, 0.4f, 0.2f, 0.5f);
    RenderSettings.fogDensity = 0.03f;

}



// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    RenderSettings.fog = IsUnderwater();
    RenderSettings.fog = IsNotUnderwater ();

}
```

Comment: your two methods code will never execute after the return statement. What is the current problem you are having?

Comment: the problem is that I woudl like diferent fog render settings appear above Y 150 than different fog render settings between Y 150 - Y 80 and than below Y 80 I would like again diferent one. Y I mean y-axis. So to simply say I would like to change the fog in three differnet levels of the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 'return' statement in most programming languages, including C#, will exit the function, returning the given value. This means that the following lines that actually affect the fog settings never get run.

There are a bunch of different ways to set this code up, here's a simple example:

```
void SetFog()
{
    if(transform.position.y >= 150)
    {
        RenderSettings.fog = true;
        return;
    }

    if(transform.position.y >= 90)
    {
        RenderSettings.fog = true;
        RenderSettings.fogColor = new Color (0.15f, 0.35f, 0.40f, 0.5f);
        RenderSettings.fogDensity = 0.03f;

        return;
    }

    RenderSettings.fog = true;
    RenderSettings.fogColor = new Color (0.8f, 0.4f, 0.2f, 0.5f);
    RenderSettings.fogDensity = 0.03f;
}

void Update()
{
    SetFog();
}
```

Keep in mind that this is a very simple solution, and not very extensible or maintainable. It may be worth adding an array of settings to the object that you can tweak in the editor, with 1 entry for each of the different heights.

Comment: hey thanks very much, so far it works and Ill keep playing with it further.